# Getting last time an Azure function ran

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In Visual Studio 2017 I created a new Azure Function project that generated the following code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {
            var lastRun = myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Last;

            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

My question is about the `lastRun` variable. Is it:

1. The last time the function ran **successfully**
2. The last time the function ran, regardless of success or failure
3. Something else entirely

I searched the Azure documentation and failed to come up with any information around the properties of the TimerInfo object so it would be helpful to understand if this variable can be used to know when the last time the function ran or not.

Answer (score 5):

The "Last" property on ScheduleStatus of TimerInfo object is the datetime when the last time function timer fired, irrespective of function run status of success or failure. And when the timer fires it would trigger the timer function execution.

Answer (score 2):

`TimerInfo.ScheduleStatus.Last`

> Gets or sets the last recorded schedule occurrence.

According to comments in the [Sourcecode on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/a3a5a49a64f3592c1eb7c1296086dc83c2011e96/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Timers/Scheduling/ScheduleStatus.cs#L16).

This doesn't indicate any relation to the *result* of the last run, so I think the answer is 2: "The last time the function ran, regardless of success or failure".

Comment: Actually, it's not the last time the function ran, but the last time the timer was triggered. If you run the function manually, it's not reflected by `Last`

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to store your function execution status somewhere else (Redis cache for example) where all functions instance can refer to centrally shared configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample for finding Last run

log.LogInformation($"Schedule Status Last: {**myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Last.ToString()**}");

```html
using System;
using System.Reflection;
 
public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
   log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
   Type timerInfo = typeof(TimerInfo);
   log.LogInformation("TimerInfo Methods:");
   MethodInfo[] methodInfo = timerInfo.GetMethods();
   foreach (MethodInfo mInfo in methodInfo)
   {
      log.LogInformation($"{mInfo.ToString()}");
   }
   log.LogInformation("TimerInfo Members:");
   MemberInfo[] memberInfo = timerInfo.GetMembers();
   foreach (MemberInfo mbInfo in memberInfo)
   {
      log.LogInformation($"{mbInfo.ToString()}");
   }
   
   log.LogInformation($"Schedule Status Last: {**myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Last.ToString()**}");
   
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that `timerInfo.ScheduleStatus.Last` returns a default DateTime once Function App gets restarted so I'm not sure if that's 100% reliable. Any alternative approaches ?